# Handling errors thown by promise in observable created by from()

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, promise, observable

I'm trying to use the AngularFire library in an Angular application. Some of the AngularFire calls return promises, and I'd like to handle them as observables instead for consistency throughout the app. I'm using rxjs v6

Using `from()` works well and gives the expected behaviour except when errors occur.

If the promise throws an exception, the observable doesn't seem to see it and a stack trace gets dumped in the console saying `Error: Uncaught (in promise)`.

*My first attempt*

The AngularFire call that returns the promise:

```
deleteCampaign(id: string) {
  return from(this.campaignCollection.doc(id).delete());
}
```

The calling code:

```
    deleteCampaign(id: string) {
        return this.dataStorageService.deleteCampaign(id)
        .pipe(
            catchError(
                err => {
                    console.log('error when deleting campaign');
                    console.log(err);
                    return throwError(err);
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

In this instance, I get the stack trace in the console and the `catchError` never fires.

*My second attempt*

I added a `catch` to the promise inside the `from`, and then tried rethrowing the error as an observable so it looked like this:

```
    deleteCampaign(id: string) {
        return from(this.campaignCollection.doc(id).delete().catch(
            err => {
                throwError(err);
            }
        ));
    }
```

*My third attempt*

Much like the second attempt, but I tried throwing a plain javascript error. This resulted in the same stack trace however, and it wasn't picked up by the observable either.

```
    deleteCampaign(id: string) {
        return from(this.campaignCollection.doc(id).delete().catch(
            err => {
                throw(err);
            }
        ));
    }
```

This stopped the stack trace happening, as now the promise was catching it, but the calling code still never sees the error.

Am I going about this the wrong way? I assumed that by using `from()` all of the error handling could occur in the observable, and I could leave the promise alone.

I need to be able to either:
1. Have no error handling code where the promise is returned and let the observable take care of it.
1. Have the promise `catch` block able to rethrow an error thats caught by the observable.

---

Here's the solution arrived at:

From the front end component, handle the passed error using the `error` callback in `subscribe`

```
  onDelete(id: string) {
    this.loadingCampaigns = true;
    this.campaignService.deleteCampaign(id).subscribe(
      _ => {},
      err => {
        console.log('error detection from the component');
      }
    );
  }
```

From the campaign service, `tap()` the error so it can be logged or otherwise:

```
    deleteCampaign(id: string) {
        return this.dataStorageService.deleteCampaign(id)
        .pipe(
            tap(null, () => {console.log('tapped the error');} ),
        );
    }
```

Finally, from the data storage component do nothing at all:

```
    deleteCampaign(id: string) {
        return from(this.campaignCollection.doc(id).delete());
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach an error callback to `Observable.subscribe()`.

```
Rx.Observable.from(Promise.reject('Boo!'))
    .subscribe(val => {
        console.log('success');
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
// Boo!
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, I added that to where `deleteCampaign()` gets called and that does indeed trap the error, however the `catchError()` block from the `pipe()` in the other observable doesn't fire.

Any way I can get that to fire as well? I'd like to put code in there logging the error out to a log provider, and keep the front end code to display to the user.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've got it sorted out now I'll update my question in case anyone else was wondering!

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteCampaign(id: string) {
  return from(this.campaignCollection.doc(id).delete()).pipe(catchError(err=>{
      return throwError(err);
    }))
}

deleteCampaign(myid).susbcribe(res=>{
    console.log(res);
},error=>{
    console.log(error)
})
```

I put an example using ng-bootstrap modal -that return a promise when open the modal- to convert to a Observable in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1yd29j?file=app/modal-basic.ts)

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the error callback when I stopped passing the observable on!